# How to select correct text in html with Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code as blow is shown some  within , I want select correct text.
But now when mouse down on SPAN and start selecting text and mouse move to the div ,a large text is selected as the image as blow.
Can I select the correct text?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB0qi.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Conditional Text Selection</title>
    <style>

    .textLayer{
        position:absolute;
        inset:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-family:monospace !important;
        line-height:1;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
         -moz-text-size-adjust:none;
              text-size-adjust:none;
        forced-color-adjust:none;
        transform-origin:0 0;
        z-index:2;
    }

 /*   .textLayer :is(br) {
        user-select: none;
    }*/

    .textLayer :is(span, br){
        position:absolute;
        white-space:pre;
        cursor:text;
        transform-origin:center left;
        display: inline;
    }

    /* 标记选中的文本 */
    ::selection {
        background: yellow;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="textLayer" data-main-rotation="0" style="width: 1200px;height: 1300px;--scale-factor: 1.96078431372549;"><span  style="left: 10.59%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.953561, 0.75);">(or, more broadly, on</span>
<span  style="left: 27.13%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 27.73%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.914235, 0.75);">mathematics</span>
<span  style="left: 37.43%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span dir="ltr" style="left: 38.22%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.962099, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_321R">generally).</span>
<span  style="left: 46.35%; top: 9.81%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">42</span>
<span  style="left: 47.73%; top: 9.81%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span dir="ltr" style="left: 48.65%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.945475, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_322R">To illustrate this converse, I single out ﬁve events in</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 10.59%; top: 11.74%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.912819, 0.75);">ﬁve diﬀerent areas of mathematics (Figure 3), triggered or made possible by logic-based developments</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 10.59%; top: 13.45%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.932114, 0.75);">in computer science, with each event deserving the distinction of being ‘ﬁrst’ in its respective area:</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.25%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.912485, 0.75);">Boolean algebra</span>
<span  style="left: 27.3%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 28.22%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.970179, 0.75);">– a formal proof that every Robbins algebra is a Boolean algebra, using the</span>
<br role="presentation"><span dir="ltr" style="left: 15.04%; top: 18%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.946777, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_323R">automated theorem-prover EQP (1997).</span>
<span  style="left: 46.2%; top: 17.78%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">43</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.25%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.929563, 0.75);">Graph theory</span>
<span  style="left: 25.08%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 25.75%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.906408, 0.75);">– a formal proof of the Four-Color Theorem using the automated interactive proof-</span>
<br role="presentation"><span dir="ltr" style="left: 15.04%; top: 21.92%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.919253, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_324R">assistant Coq (2008).</span>
<span  style="left: 31.51%; top: 21.7%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">44</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.25%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.948306, 0.75);">Group theory</span>
<span  style="left: 25.34%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 26.24%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.94688, 0.75);">– a formal proof of the Odd-Order Theorem, also known as the Feit-Thompson</span>
<br role="presentation"><span dir="ltr" style="left: 15.04%; top: 25.84%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.935484, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_325R">Theorem, using the automated interactive proof-assistant Coq (2012).</span>
<span  style="left: 69.61%; top: 25.63%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">45</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.26%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.909879, 0.75);">Three-dimensional geometry</span>
<span  style="left: 36.86%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDpM3.png)
Result actually:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIKmY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Would tell problem is [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03292.pdf#page=11) source / conversion, you may either consolidate it a bit like discussed here [Reorganize PDF or HTML content for a blind user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209790/reorganize-pdf-or-html-content-for-a-blind-user) or use better converter.

In case I just copy HTML from pdf.js (say in Firefox), I will probably get better output like:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<div class="textLayer" style="width: round(var(--scale-factor) * 612px, 1px); height: round(var(--scale-factor) * 792px, 1px);" data-main-rotation="0"><span style="left: 10.59%; top: 9.95%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.01002);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">(or, more broadly, on</span><span style="left: 27.13%; top: 9.95%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 27.73%; top: 9.95%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.95716);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">mathematics</span><span style="left: 37.43%; top: 9.95%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 38.22%; top: 9.95%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.974415);" dir="ltr" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_321R">generally).</span><span style="left: 46.35%; top: 9.75%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.00382);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">42</span><span style="left: 47.73%; top: 9.75%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 48.65%; top: 9.95%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.00191);" dir="ltr" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_322R">To illustrate this converse, I single out ﬁve events in</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 10.59%; top: 11.66%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.967885);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">
ﬁve diﬀerent areas of mathematics (Figure 3), triggered or made possible by logic-based developments</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 10.59%; top: 13.37%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.995195);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">
in computer science, with each event deserving the distinction of being ‘ﬁrst’ in its respective area:</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 13.25%; top: 16.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr">•</span><span style="left: 14.15%; top: 16.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 16.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.941125);" role="presentation" 
dir="ltr">Boolean algebra</span><span style="left: 27.3%; top: 16.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 28.22%; top: 16.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.02905);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">– a formal proof that every Robbins algebra is a Boolean algebra, using the</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 17.92%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.985284);" dir="ltr" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_323R" class="">automated theorem-prover EQP (1997).</span><span style="left: 46.2%; top: 17.72%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.00382);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">43</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 13.25%; top: 20.13%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr">•</span><span style="left: 14.15%; top: 20.13%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 20.13%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.961381);" role="presentation" 
dir="ltr">Graph theory</span><span style="left: 25.08%; top: 20.13%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 25.75%; top: 20.13%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.983501);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">– a formal proof of the Four-Color Theorem using the automated interactive proof-</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 21.84%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.968603);" dir="ltr" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_324R">assistant Coq (2008).</span><span style="left: 31.51%; top: 21.65%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.00382);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">44</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 13.25%; top: 24.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr">•</span><span style="left: 14.15%; top: 24.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 24.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.985783);" role="presentation" 
dir="ltr">Group theory</span><span style="left: 25.34%; top: 24.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 26.24%; top: 24.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.01757);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">– a formal proof of the Odd-Order Theorem, also known as the Feit-Thompson</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 25.77%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.988668);" dir="ltr" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_325R">Theorem, using the automated interactive proof-assistant Coq (2012).</span><span style="left: 69.61%; top: 25.57%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.00382);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">45</span><br role="presentation"><span style="left: 13.26%; top: 27.99%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr">•</span><span style="left: 14.15%; top: 27.99%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;" role="presentation" dir="ltr"> </span><span style="left: 15.04%; top: 27.99%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.958323);" role="presentation" 
dir="ltr">Three-dimensional geometry</span>
```

Where selection probably work normal.

There is problem with `position: absolute` if I try your code again and change pointer event as mentioned here
[css absolute position blocks text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010428/css-absolute-position-blocks-text-selection) it seems to work better. Border added for better elements orientation.

```css
div.textLayer {
  pointer-events: none;
}
span {
  border:1px solid red;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Conditional Text Selection</title>
    <style>

    .textLayer{
        position:absolute;
        inset:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-family:monospace !important;
        line-height:1;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
         -moz-text-size-adjust:none;
              text-size-adjust:none;
        forced-color-adjust:none;
        transform-origin:0 0;
        z-index:2;
    }

    .textLayer :is(span, br){
        position:absolute;
        white-space:pre;
        cursor:text;
        transform-origin:center left;
        display: inline;
    }

    /* 标记选中的文本 */
    ::selection {
        background: yellow;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="textLayer" data-main-rotation="0" style="width: 1200px;height: 1300px;--scale-factor: 1.96078431372549;"><span  style="left: 10.59%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.953561, 0.75);">(or, more broadly, on</span>
<span  style="left: 27.13%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 27.73%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.914235, 0.75);">mathematics</span>
<span  style="left: 37.43%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span dir="ltr" style="left: 38.22%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.962099, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_321R">generally).</span>
<span  style="left: 46.35%; top: 9.81%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">42</span>
<span  style="left: 47.73%; top: 9.81%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span dir="ltr" style="left: 48.65%; top: 10.03%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.945475, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_322R">To illustrate this converse, I single out ﬁve events in</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 10.59%; top: 11.74%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.912819, 0.75);">ﬁve diﬀerent areas of mathematics (Figure 3), triggered or made possible by logic-based developments</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 10.59%; top: 13.45%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.932114, 0.75);">in computer science, with each event deserving the distinction of being ‘ﬁrst’ in its respective area:</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.25%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.912485, 0.75);">Boolean algebra</span>
<span  style="left: 27.3%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 28.22%; top: 16.28%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.970179, 0.75);">– a formal proof that every Robbins algebra is a Boolean algebra, using the</span>
<br role="presentation"><span dir="ltr" style="left: 15.04%; top: 18%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.946777, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_323R">automated theorem-prover EQP (1997).</span>
<span  style="left: 46.2%; top: 17.78%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">43</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.25%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.929563, 0.75);">Graph theory</span>
<span  style="left: 25.08%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 25.75%; top: 20.21%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.906408, 0.75);">– a formal proof of the Four-Color Theorem using the automated interactive proof-</span>
<br role="presentation"><span dir="ltr" style="left: 15.04%; top: 21.92%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.919253, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_324R">assistant Coq (2008).</span>
<span  style="left: 31.51%; top: 21.7%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">44</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.25%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.948306, 0.75);">Group theory</span>
<span  style="left: 25.34%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 26.24%; top: 24.15%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.94688, 0.75);">– a formal proof of the Odd-Order Theorem, also known as the Feit-Thompson</span>
<br role="presentation"><span dir="ltr" style="left: 15.04%; top: 25.84%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.935484, 0.75);" aria-owns="pdfjs_internal_id_325R">Theorem, using the automated interactive proof-assistant Coq (2012).</span>
<span  style="left: 69.61%; top: 25.63%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*7.97px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.881791, 0.75);">45</span>
<br role="presentation"><span  style="left: 13.26%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;">•</span>
<span  style="left: 14.15%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
<span  style="left: 15.04%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scale(0.909879, 0.75);">Three-dimensional geometry</span>
<span  style="left: 36.86%; top: 28.07%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*10.91px); font-family: sans-serif;"> </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm debugging PDF.js with chrome, When mouse moves over the textLayer DIV, the selection text is covered all the text in DIV. 
I just want the selection text is changed when mouse moves over SPAN

Comment: If pointer-events is added, the selection text is from the left top, the effect likes: user-select: none/text